# how to trivially adapt set or map ordering predicate for pointers

Tags: c++, set, std, shared-ptr

There must be a trivial answer to this...

I have a std::set or a std::map or some object type which has a natural ordering - say std::less.

I need to change my set or map to contain shared_ptr instead of copies of T.

So I want something like:

```
using my_set std::set<std::shared_ptr<T>, std::less<*T>>;
```

But I'm drawing a blank as to how to specify "use the less adaptor on ____ adaptor of T so that it's on dereferenced members, not on shared_ptrs!"

Is there a `std::less<std::dereference<std::shared_ptr<T>>>` equivalent?

Comment: Write a custom comparator?

Comment: Absolutely can do that.  My question is: isn't there a standard adaptor for this?  It must come up a ton!

Comment: Not sure since the compare function must take `T` which is a pointer type.  Something like `std::less<std::dereference<std::shared_ptr<T>>>` would expect a `T`.

Comment: There's nothing in the standard library you can use off the shelf. You need to compose your own comparator.

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no functor in the C++ standard library to achieve what you want. You can either write a custom comparator, or if you need this functionality often, come up with an `indirect`/`dereference` function object.

Related and potentially helpful threads; the first one offers a generic solution for many operators (even if it requires a bit of code):

- [Why do several of the standard operators not have standard functors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6336025)
- [Functor that calls a function after dereferencing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6269313)
- [Less-than function dereferencing pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14090043)

Comment: Thank you.  These look promising to help understand the issue and why this corner of C++ is still a major PIA.

Answer (score 2):

While the standard library may not already provide what you need, I think it's pretty trivial to write your own `std::dereference_less`:

```
#include <memory>
#include <set>

namespace std
{
    template<typename T>
    struct dereference_less
    {
        constexpr bool operator ()(const T& _lhs, const T& _rhs) const
        {
            return *_lhs < *_rhs;
        }
    };
}

int main()
{
   using key_type = std::shared_ptr<int>;
   std::set<key_type, std::dereference_less<key_type>> mySet;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/48e70a22a55ed80a) (refactored a bit to have a template type alias like in your question)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already changing your internal interface to something that requires dereferencing you could also just write a wrapper class and provide a `bool operator< ()` as follows:

```
#include <memory>   // shared_ptr
#include <set>      // set
#include <iostream> // cout
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class wrapper
{
public:
  shared_ptr<T> sp;

  bool operator< (const wrapper<T>& rhs) const
  {
    return  *( sp.get() ) < *( rhs.sp.get() ) ;
  }
  wrapper(){}
  wrapper(shared_ptr<T> sp):sp(sp){}
};

int main()
{
  shared_ptr<int> sp1 (new int);
  *sp1 = 1;
  shared_ptr<int> sp2 (new int);
  *sp2 = 2;

  set<wrapper<int>> S;
  S.insert(wrapper<int>(sp2));
  S.insert(wrapper<int>(sp1));

  for (auto& j : S)
    cout << *(j.sp) << endl;

  return 0;
}
```